# What does "死党" mean?

Tags: meaning, word

My first impression to this word is something like "enemy" or "enemies", because the letter "死" is used and it means death.

But when I do some search, it means "sworn followers"?
I really doubt at it. Can anyone explain?

Comment: bkrs： 死党 best friends inseparable sidekick
diehard followers sworn/diehard followers; partisans sworn to die  **2) 为某人或集团出死力的党羽。含贬义**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**死** means 赴死 or 尽死力 ((worth) dying for / giving all one's strength).

**党** means 朋党 (clique; cabal; faction).

[**死党**](http://www.zdic.net/c/b/13b/301064.htm) means "pursue private ends" at first,

> [pursue private ends]∶ 为自己的朋党拼死竭力
>
> 案后将军朱博、 钜鹿太守 孙闳,故光禄大夫 陈咸( 王)立交通厚善,相与为腹心,有背心死党之信,欲相攀援,死而后已。——《汉书·瞿方进传》

And means "sworn followers; diehard followers" (with derogatory sence),

> [sworn followers; diehard followers]∶效死的党羽
>
> 网罗死党

Nowadays it usually means **"best friend"**.

> 比喻情誼深厚的朋友。

Reference: [文化漫谈：为什么好朋友又称为“死党”？有何典故由来？](http://wemedia.ifeng.com/21700187/wemedia.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

It means best friends or very close friends. No bad meaning involved.

Answer (score 0):

it means sb is your follower. also same with "老铁". u guys know each other very well.